# How do I push/set data into firebase using AWS Lambda nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am quite new to aws lambda and am not sure how to set data into firebase using it. Below is my code so far:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;  

var config = {
    apiKey: "cannot be shown",
    authDomain: "cannot be shown",
    databaseURL: "cannot be shown",
    projectId: "cannot be shown",
    storageBucket: "cannot be shown",
    messagingSenderId: "cannot be shown"
};

if(firebase.apps.length === 0) {   
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/').set({
    username: "test",
    email: "test@mail.com"
    });

    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda'); 
};

};
```

From this, how am I able to do so or is my code done wrong?